# Jacobson radical of the integral group ring

Tags: representation-theory, group-rings

I am trying to prove that the Jacobson radical of the integral group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$  for a finite group is zero. Most of what I find on semisimplicity, Jacobson semisimplicity, has to do with group algebras $KG$ where $K$ is a field. I did come across this,

[Jacobson radical of a ring finitely generated over $\mathbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829987/jacobson-radical-of-a-ring-finitely-generated-over-mathbb-z)

but it does not seem to apply here, as the Jacobson radical would only vanish for PID an Dedekind rings.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Laurent: my answer there is only concerning commutative rings - in your case, is $G$ abelian?

Comment: No it's not. That's also why I thought it would not apply too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have located a proof as lemma 4.1 in the following article:

> Akasaki, T. (1972). Idempotent ideals in integral group rings. *Journal of Algebra*, *23*(2), 343–346.

The article is [available online](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869372901354), but the proof is short, so I reproduce it here:

> $\rm L{\small EMMA}$ 4.1. Let $\pi$ be any finite group. Then the Jacobson radical of $\mathbb{Z}\pi$ is zero.
>
> *Proof.* For a given ring $R$, let its Jacobson radical be written as $J(R)$. Let $p$ be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\eta_p: \mathbb{Z}\pi \to \mathbb{Z}_p \pi$ be coefficient reduction. Since $\eta_p$ is a ring epimorphism, $J(\mathbb{Z}\pi)$ is contained in the inverse image $\eta_p^{-1}(J(\mathbb{Z}_p \pi))$. Thus if $p \nmid |\pi|$ then, by Maschke’s theorem, $J(\mathbb{Z}\pi) \subset \ker(\eta_p)$. Therefore, if $\lambda \in J(\mathbb{Z}\pi)$, $\lambda \in \ker(\eta_p)$ for infinitely many primes $p \nmid |\pi|$. This means that $\lambda = 0$ and hence $J(\mathbb{Z}\pi) = (0)$.