# Jacobson radical of integral group ring $\mathbb ZS_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, group-rings

> I want to know whether Jacobson radical of integral group ring $\mathbb ZS_3$ ($S_3$ is the symmetric group) is known or not.

Please help me. Tell me about any reference. Also if anyone knows about the maximal ideals of it.

Comment: For any finite group, the Jacobson radical of its integral group ring is zero. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903632/jacobson-radical-of-the-integral-group-ring/1635205#1635205)

Comment: thanku so much.  now i got very important result known to me.

Comment: @MittalG hlo sir can you look at my problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025927/exponent-of-the-non-abelian-group-1jfg-for-finite-non-abelian-p-group-g ...thanks